# Selligent ignoring image size within outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have never used this program before (new job and new programs) and have already noticed some weird quirks of it. For example if I put a p tag around a dynamic div tag (it will ignore any style directly within the div, as as such need put it in the p tag surrounding it) it will work initially, though when I edit the email in the future it will dump the div tag outside the p tag, so because of that I am not sure if my next problem is a quirk of Selligent or not.

My question is that the size of header image works in all browsers except outlook (in outlook the size of the image becomes far larger then the specified size of 537px). The email has also been written with the CSS in the bottom of the email (I did not create this email, I have to try and fix their existing ones, I also know there are quite a few redundancies within it), could this be causing the problems as well?

```
<div id="masection" maconstraint="SYSTEM.MAIL=1" mahidediv="true">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

        <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td align="center">

                <p><a style="font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;" href="~PROBE(0)~">View this email in your browser.</a></p>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>



<div>

    <table class="container" style="background-color: #ffffff; max-width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 0%;" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">

        <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><tr><td><![endif]-->

                <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">

                    <table style=" border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" draggable="true">

                        <tbody>

                            <tr>

                                <td style="font-size: 12px;text-align:center;padding-bottom:0px; " class="c-over sim-ml-middle">

                                <p><span style="font-size: 14px;">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</p>



                                <p><img alt="" style="width: 537px; height: 90px;" src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/CountryLiving/Country_Living_logo20012016.fw.png" /><br />

                                &nbsp;</p>



                                <hr />

                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="font-size:18px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>Your first issue of Country Living&nbsp;will arrive soon!</strong></span></span></p>



                                <hr />

                                <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: right;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Your subscriber number is:&nbsp;~(RIGHT('000000000000'& (TRANS_SUB_MAINLINK.CDS_CUSTOMER_ID),12))~</span><br />





                                <b><div id="MASECTION" macontenteditable="FALSE" maconstraint="" maparameter="LAST_ISSUE_PARAMETER" matype="" mahidediv="TRUE" contenteditable="FALSE" maclass="" malanguage="" mashowalllanguages="FALSE" mastyle="">

                                </div></b></p>





                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><br />

                                <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Dear ~FORENAME~,</span><br />

                                &nbsp;</span></p>



                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">Just a quick update to let you know that your&nbsp;</span><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">first&nbsp;copy of </span><em><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">Country Living</span></em><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;"> will be with you soon, and should arrive around </span></span></span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">~(FORMATDATETIME(SUBS_DATES.UK_SALE_DATE,'%d %B %Y'))~</span><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">. </span></span></span><br />

                                <br />

                                <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><!--StartFragment--></span></span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; vertical-align: baseline;">In the meantime, if you need to update your personal details or check the status of your subscription you can</span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; vertical-align: baseline;"> </span><a href="~PROBE(109)~"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">manage your account online</span></a><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">. If you still can't find what you're looking for and require further information, please see our<a href="~PROBE(110)~"> </a></span><a href="~PROBE(110)~"><u style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: blue; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">FAQs</span></u></a><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;"> or </span><a href="~PROBE(111)~"><u style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: blue; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">Contact Us</span></u></a><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;"> </span><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; vertical-align: baseline;">and we will happily assist you.</span></p>



                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><br />

                                <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0pt; background-color: #ffffff; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline;">All future delivery dates can be viewed </span><a href="~PROBE(108)~"><u style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: blue; letter-spacing: 0pt; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline;">here.</span></u></a></p>



                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><br />

                                <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;">Thank you for subscribing to </span><span style="letter-spacing: 0pt; vertical-align: baseline;"><em>Country Living</em>.</span></span></span><br />

                                <br />

                                &nbsp;</p>



                                <p style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">The Country Living Customer Care Team</span></span></p>

                                <br />

                                <hr /></td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

                </div>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>



    <table class="container" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;max-width:600px;border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><tr><td ><![endif]-->

                <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">

                    <p></p>

                    <br />

                    <br />

                    &nbsp;

                </div>

                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->

</div>

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><tr><td><![endif]-->



<table class="container" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:600px;border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><tr><td><![endif]-->

            <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">

                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style=" border-collapse:collapse;mso-cellspacing:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">

                    <tbody>

                        <tr>

                            <td style="width:20px;height:20px;"><img border="0" align="left" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;" src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/Training/Spacer_01.gif" /></td>

                            <td style="color:#31313F;padding-bottom:4px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;font-family:Palatino Linotype, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;font-weight:500;border-top:1px solid #f2f2f2;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;" class="aligncenter paddinglr20"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://hearst.emsecure.net/optiext/optiextension.dll?id=PnkPFoV%2BZ5Y1zhmD5hSP8poysZWLO2gTRCsfhaRMNfgKFppIp_lxA5MXNxJzxMMRYIXgfOVJJ54SDwsAO_9UvDg4t_kPPf"><img border="0" align="center" alt="" style="height:auto;width:auto;" src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/Training/HearstUKLogo.png" /></a><br />

                            <br />

                            <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">This email and any attached files are intended for the named addressee only.<br />

                            <br />

                            Hearst magazines will only ever send email communications to those who have agreed to receive them. You are receiving this email because you signed up to receive communications from us. Please visit <a href="~PROBE(107)~">hearst.co.uk/dp</a> to view our privacy policy and full terms and conditions.<br />

                            <br />

                            The National Magazine Company Limited trading as Hearst Magazines UK<br />

                            Registered Address: 72 Broadwick Street, London, W1F 9EP<br />

                            Registered in England - Company Number: 112955</span><br />

                            <br />

                            <br />

                            &nbsp;</td>

                            <td style="width:20px;height:20px;"><img border="0" align="left" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;" src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/Training/Spacer_01.gif" /></td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {

    .container {

        width: 600px!important;

    }   

}



@media screen and (max-width: 601px){

     .col3{

        width: 100%!important;

    }

    .fullwidth{

        width:100%!important;   

    }



    .fiftywidth{

        width:50%!important;    

    }



    .bordernone{

    border:none!important;

    }



    .eightypercent{

        width:80%!important;    

    }



    .roundel{

        width:50%!important;    

    }



    .displaynone{

    display:none!important;

    }

    .aligncenter{

    text-align:center!important;

    }



    .ptext{

    font-size:16px!important;

    }



    .htext{

    font-size:27px!important;

    }



    .lhtext{

    font-size:35px!important;

    }



    .nopaddingbottom{

    padding-bottom:0px!important;   

    }



    .nopaddingtop{

    padding-top:0px!important;  

    }



    .nopadding{

    padding:0px!important;  

    }



    .nopaddinglr{

    padding-left:0px!important; 

    padding-right:0px!important;    

    }



    .paddingbottom20{

    padding-bottom:20px!important;  

    }



    .paddingbottom10{

    padding-bottom:10px!important;  

    }



    .paddingbottom30{

    padding-bottom:30px!important;  

    }



    .paddingtop30{

    padding-top:30px!important; 

    }





    .paddingtop20{

    padding-top:20px!important; 

    }



    .height20{

    height:20px!important;  

    }



.paddinglr20{

    padding-left:20px!important;

                    padding-right:20px!important;   

    }



}



@media screen and (max-width: 800px){



}



@media only screen and (max-width: 480px),

    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),

    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

        table[class="button"] {width: 100% !important;}

        table[class="button"] td[class="buttonTop"] {padding: 0 !important; font-size: 1.3em !important; }

        table[class="button"] td[class="buttonTop"] a {padding: 1em 0 1em 0 !important; display: block !important; }

        table[class="button"] td[class="buttonBottom"] {font-size: 1.4em !important; display: block !important; }

    }

</style>
```

Comment: Instead of style="width: 537px, you should give width="537" . I think this might help you out.

Comment: On a random note, I did try that. Though outlook ignored that as well, and then when I edited it again the code reverted back to the previous version......Which makes me think this a selligent thing....

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is ancient, but in case someone else needs a remedy... Outlook doesn't resize images, so the image needs to be exact size you want it to appear within the newsletter. In looking at the header image URL in your code, the size is 1213x191. You'd need to create a version of the image sized to the newsletter header spec (e.g. 537x85) and use that one instead.

This isn't only an issue with Selligent. It happens in other ESPs delivering messages to Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

What avjones mentions is right. In addition, if you do want to use an image that is greater than the width of your email whilst still making is reduce to the correct size in Outlook you can use ghost/mso tables. These are tables only picked up by IE rendering.

I notice you already have them in your code, you have your table container with a width of 600px and an mso table inside with a width of 100%. This mso table will only be read by Outlook, so try changing that width to 600px. Make sure that it is also closed properly. I usually also insert the closing tags. Like so:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <![endif]-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="center">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
                            <img src="http://hearst.emsecure.net/images/CountryLiving/Country_Living_logo20012016.fw.png" style="display:block;width:100%;" border="0" width="600" alt="Country Living" title="" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also find examples on popular email websites.